# Replay traffic captured using tcpreplay

Tags: networking, tcp, network-traffic, tcpreplay

We have PCAP dump which has TCP packets. These packets are captured on a network interface.

Now i want to replay these packets from my `"Server A" ----> "Server B"`. The server **"A"** and server **"B"** are in local LAN network and there is a switch in between.

```
Server A   <-------Switch-----> Server B
```

To send traffic from "A" to "B", we have changed the dst Ip and dst MAC of the packets in PCAP file to dst IP and dst MAC of server **B**.

Below is the command used

```
tcprewrite --infile=udp_lite_full_coverage_0.pcap --outfile=test_2.pcap --dstipmap=0.0.0.0/0:10.76.110.84/26 --enet-dmac=34:17:EB:AF:7E:EA
```

Then we replayed the traffic from server **"A"** eth0 using below command

```
sudo tcpreplay --loop=0 --intf1=eth0 test_2.pcap
```

**Eth0** of **"B"** is reachable from **"B"**.

With the above i expect the packets to be seen at eth0 of server **"B"**. But i am not seeing any packet at server **B**. Can you please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replay previously recorded traffic into a TCP server. TCP servers issue a random sequence number during 3-way handshake. Replayed traffic will be using a different starting sequence number, which the server will reject it.

UDP works, TCP doesn't.